# z3py on MacOSX: cannot get a model

Tags: z3, z3py

I am seeing a strange problem with z3py on Mac, was wondering if anyone has seen this before:

```
$ cat bug.py
from z3 import *       
x = Int('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(x > 5)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
$ python bug.py
sat
[x = ]
```

The value of x is missing from the model. I tried both master and unstable branches with the same result. However, z3 itself does give the correct model if run on a similar .smt2 file. My configuration is Mac OSX 10.6.8, Python 2.7.4.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is very specific for my setup, but maybe someone will run into it as well: the root cause is that a wrong version of libgomp was picked up by the dynamic loader -- i.e. the versions used to compile and to run do not match.

Here is a more severe manifestation of this issue:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, May  9 2013, 18:51:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from z3 import *
>>> IntVal(1)

>>>
```

The numeric value is not printed, i.e. the correct output is

```
>>> IntVal(1)
1
>>>
```

Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the correct version of the library fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems with Z3 4.1 and Python 2.7.2 on my Mac OSX 10.8.3. I wonder if it's some sort of terminal issue that eats the characters for whatever reason. What do you see if you redirect the output to a file? (i.e., try "python bug.py > out". Does the contents of the file "out" look OK?)

Comment: Same content as on console. I have a feeling it might have something to do with my python install.